# Display child records in single column by comma separted with parent records

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-12c

Have parent & child table like below for Oracle

T_OPT_PARENT

```
OPT | OPT_DESC| STATUS 
XY  | XY_DESC | A 
YZ  | YZ_DESC | A 
ZZ  | ZZ_DESC | A
```

T_OPT_CHILD

```
OPT | CODE
XY  | ONE_CODE
XY  | TWO_CODE
XY  | THREE_CODE
ZZ  | ONE_CODE
ZZ  | TWO_CODE
```

Expected OutPut

```
OPT | OPT_DESC| CODE                 | STATUS 
XY  | XY_DESC | ONE_CODE,TWO_CODE,THREE_CODE | A
YZ  | YZ_DESC |                              | A 
ZZ  | ZZ_DESC | ONE_CODE, TWO_CODE           | A
```

Could some one help me to construct SQL to obtain the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup tables and data:

```
create table T_OPT_PARENT
(OPT       char(2)
,OPT_DESC  varchar2(10)
,STATUS    char(1));

insert into T_OPT_PARENT
select 'XY','XY_DESC','A' from dual union all
select 'YZ','YZ_DESC','A' from dual union all
select 'ZZ','ZZ_DESC','A' from dual;

create table T_OPT_CHILD
(OPT       char(2)
,CODE      varchar2(10));

insert into T_OPT_CHILD
select 'XY','ONE_CODE'   from dual union all
select 'XY','TWO_CODE'   from dual union all
select 'XY','THREE_CODE' from dual union all
select 'ZZ','ONE_CODE'   from dual union all
select 'ZZ','TWO_CODE'   from dual;
```

Here's one solution based on a `left join` and the `listagg()` function:

```
select p.OPT,
       p.OPT_DESC,
       listagg(c.CODE, ', ') within group (order by ROWNUM) "CODE",
       p.STATUS

from T_OPT_PARENT p

left
join T_OPT_CHILD c
on   c.OPT = p.OPT

group by p.OPT, 
         p.OPT_DESC,
         p.STATUS

order by 1;

 OPT | OPT_DESC | CODE                           | STATUS
 --- | -------- | ------------------------------ | ------
 XY  | XY_DESC  | ONE_CODE, TWO_CODE, THREE_CODE | A     
 YZ  | YZ_DESC  | null                           | A     
 ZZ  | ZZ_DESC  | ONE_CODE, TWO_CODE             | A
```

NOTE: I'm able to sort `XY`'s CODE as desired using `ROWNUM` **only** because I inserted the records into the `T_OPT_CHILD` table in the same order as the desired sort order.  The use of `ROWNUM` may not work for your real world data so you'll likely need to modify the `order by ROWNUM` clause accordingly.

Here's a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=81086e82328ea93a7c8dbf78bcd17a12)